# mac login screen background

Tags: macos, desktop, background

I have a super annoying problem when I log into my mac and there is not a user selected. Then I see this ugly background, that I really do not like:

[image]

I changed the background at both of my users, but it does not help:

[image]
[image]

It was the same for Monterey, and the Update to Ventura did not help.

The background of the login screen, when there are no user selected does not match any of the 2 login screens of the users. So how can I change the background of the login screen **when there are no user selected?**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: sure, I updated it. :)